# Impedance of current probe

Tags: oscilloscope, current-measurement, probe

Does anybody know the impedance of the Tektronix A622 current probe? I don't find it neither on the datasheet, nor in the user manual...

**EDIT**: As requested, here is some extra info: I need the *output* impedance of the probe, for proper impedance matching with the scope. And no, it's *not* printed on the label of the probe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you say, the required output imedance doesn't seem to be mentioned in the manual (or both of us can't read), but they say you can hook it up to a multimeter with a BNC-to-Banana adapter. I am not aware of any multimeter with a 50 Ohm input impedance, so I guess the porbe's output is a voltage buffer designed to drive a device with a high-Z input like a multimeter or a 1 MOhm scope input. (If this was not the case, you'd get readings that would be wrong by about a factor of 2.)

Also, the corner frequency of the probe is 100 kHz, which doesn't really require a defined 50 Ohm transmission line with termination.

So no, I don't know for sure - but yes, I think 1 MOhm with some pF in parallel is most likely the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most probes will list on the side of the probe or on the connector somewhere the impedance of it.  I think common impedance is 1M or 10M, with around 15pF of capacitance.

Comment: this probe is a hall affect sensor, this means that it should just be measuring the magnetic field and have almost no affect on the signal, it probably filters some higher frequencies by having a large ferrite around the cable. It requires batteries and outputs a voltage as a function of measured magnetic field.

Comment: @Kortuk: Can you elaborate on that in an answer? I'm puzzled, because Agilent has also current probes that come with a power supply (e.g. N2782A) and in their spec sheets it is clearly stated that the probes are designed for 1M impedance oscilloscopes and special adapters are needed to make them work properly with 50\$\Omega\$ impedance scopes.

Comment: @Count Zero - Kortuk was describing the probe's effect *on the signal being measured*, not the *measurement output impedance*. Clarifying which you are interested in would help.

Comment: @FakeName: I'm obviously interested in the output impedance, so I can get a correct reading of what I measure (e.g. rise time).

Comment: @Count Zero - there is nothing "obvious" about that fact. Please clarify your question (You can edit your question very easily, you know).